# How to do a proper cleanup of TCP socket connections

Tags: c#, docker, sockets, swagger, microservices

As explained [this morning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74808162/different-threads-try-to-handle-the-same-tcp-socket-can-this-cause-instability), I'm dealing with unstable TCP socket communication. I thought this might be related to multithreading, but now I'm going on another track: when my application is finished, there still seem to be some sockets open, as you can see from this `netstat` result ("10.1.0.160" is the IP address of the remote machine I'm connecting to and the status equals `TIME_WAIT` or `ESTABLISHED`):

```
Prompt> netstat -aon | findstr "10.1.0.160"
  TCP    My_IP:56246      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56247      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56248      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56249      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56250      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56251      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56252      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56253      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56254      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56255      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56256      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56257      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56258      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56259      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56260      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56261      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56262      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:56263      10.1.0.160:50001       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    My_IP:57185      10.1.0.160:3389        ESTABLISHED     31220
  TCP    My_IP:61121      10.1.0.160:445         ESTABLISHED     4
```

In order to solve this, I first thought of implementing a destructor, but apparently this is not called, so I went declaring my TCP socket related classes as implementing the `IDisposable` interface, more or less as follows (for the class, containing the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`):

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Debug.WriteLine(
      $"T[{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}], " + 
      $"{DateTime.UtcNow}: TcpConnection.Dispose()");
    StateChanged = null; // this event is called when the state changes.
    Disconnect(); // this contains "socket.Close();"
}
```

However, when I close my application, this `Dispose()` is not called.
My application is a Swagger handled microservice. In order to close it, I just close my Swagger window.

What can I do in order to get the `Dispose()` methods called when closing the Swagger browser?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are closed properly. https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `using` statement in C#. It'll automatically call `dispose()` method when the object goes out of scope.

Here is an example:

```
using (var swaggerBrowser = new SwaggerBrowser())
{
    // Use the Swagger browser here
}
```